# Find a text in a given column from differents columns in Excel

Tags: excel, text

I have a excel column with different names, for example :

```
       a

1     name1
2     name2
3     name2
4     name6
..
1000  name 298
```

and also have different columns that gives a rande to the `$a` column , for example

```
       c        d       e

1    RANGE1   RANGE2  Range3
2    name1    name5   name8
3    name2    name6   name9
4    name3    name7   name10
5    name4            name11
```

and i would like to make a column `$b` that checks the column `$a`  for a text and outputs its range name
in this case it would be

```
       b
1    RANGE1
2    RANGE1
3    RANGE1
4    RANGE2
...
1000 RANGE30
```

i have tried to make the formula with `=if(a1=c2,c1,if(a1=c2,c1,if(..........))` but as you can see it would take forever , and i dont know how to make it less complex and less time consuming .
do you have any idea?
Thank you in advance and have a great day

Comment: `name7` belongs to both `RANGE2` and `RANGE3` is it correct? and how to detect to which range name belongs in this case? and also how many ranges do you have?

Comment: no it only belong to `RANGE2` , that was a typo , thank you , and i have something like 12 RANGES

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one in `B1`:

```
=INDEX($1:$1,1,MAX(IF($C:$E=A1,COLUMN($C$1:$E$1))))
```

and press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd> to evaluate it and then drag formula down.

To make formula faster I suggets you to change `$C:$E`, to exact range, say `$C$1:$E$100`
[image]

**UPD**

**non-volatile version**: use next formula in `B1`

```
=INDEX($C$1:$E$1,MAX(IFERROR(MATCH(IF($C$1:$E$100=A1,$C$1:$E$1,""),$C$1:$E$1,0),-1)))
```

with array entry (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd>) and drag it down.

Comment: thank you for your reply , i have tried the first formula but i didnt understand it , and i have different excel ranges , i have modified the second one and i only get `#Value!` here it is my formula `=INDEX($Z$2:$AK$2,MAX(IFERROR(MATCH(IF($Z$2:$AK$7=D3,$Z$2:$AK$2,""),$Z$2:$AK$2,0),-1)))` , pretty much my name column is on `d3` and the range column is from `z2` (where `z2` is the name of the range,for example `RANGE1` ) to `ak7` , but yet it doesn't run , do you have any idea why ?

Comment: 1) check wheter your names from column D and Z:AK really matches (e.g. there is no additional leading/trailing spaces) 2) check wheter you press CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER instead just ENTER to evaluate the formula

Comment: 3) first formula for your ranges would be `=INDEX($2:$2,1,MAX(IF(TRIM($Z$2:$AK$7)=TRIM(D3),COLUMN($Z$2:$AK$2))))` - here `IF(TRIM($Z$2:$AK$7)=TRIM(D3),COLUMN($Z$2:$AK$2))` if it finds value from `D3` in `$Z$2:$AK$7`, it returns column number where it's found (e.g. Z=26, AK=38). next step `INDEX(2:2,1,col)` returns value from second row from column, we found above. 
4) for second formula try `=INDEX($Z$2:$AK$2,MAX(IFERROR(MATCH(IF(TRIM($Z$2:$AK$7)=TRIM(D3),$Z$2:$AK$2,""),$Z$2:$AK$2,0),-1)))` 5) also here is test workbook: https://www.dropbox.com/s/v1hnepyz4ta6tlf/test.xlsx